# VBA - Trying to Select a single column, columns() is selecting that column and every greater than it?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

```
Private Sub FormatSheet()
'
' This fucntion is called to correctly format the sheet headings, given the
'  input worksheet (as a Boolean True/False).
'

'

    'Find the first empty column; Populate Column titles
    iColumn = FindEmptyColumn(3)
    Cells(3, iColumn).Value = "Outer Surface"
    Cells(3, iColumn + 1).Value = "Inner Surface"
    Cells(3, iColumn + 2).Value = "Average"

    'Set Column Formatting
    Columns(iColumn).ColumnWidth = 12
    Columns(iColumn + 1).ColumnWidth = 12.57
    Columns(iColumn + 2).ColumnWidth = 8.43
    Columns(iColumn).Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.0000"
    Columns(iColumn + 1).Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.0000"
    Columns(iColumn + 2).Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.0000"

End Sub

Public Function FindEmptyColumn(ByVal iRow As Long) As Long
'
' This function finds the first empty cell in a column given the input row
'

'
    Dim dCounter As Double
    Dim iColumnLocal As Long
    dCounter = 1
    Do Until Cells(iRow, dCounter) = ""
        iColumnLocal = dCounter
        dCounter = dCounter + 1
    Loop
    iColumnLocal = iColumnLocal + 1
    FindEmptyColumn = iColumnLocal

End Function
```

In this code, iColumn is a variable of type `Long` (it is found in my `FindEmptyColumn' function) that is just the column number of the first empty column in my data.  I am having problems with the part where I am setting the number format.  Instead of selecting on the single column, the code is selecting that column and every that are greater than it.

And I think it just starting doing this... Not sure why.

Comment: do you have merged cells, that intersects with your column?

Comment: Your code works for me. I suspect `simoco` is rigth `+1` the you have merged cells on the sheet? I updated your code (see below) to use `Find` to get the next empty cell

Comment: Yes, I have merged cells.  So, I need to update it with the correct row numbers to get it to ignore the merged cells?

Comment: And, I don't finding the first actual empty column will work; On of of my sheets I had to add a row of hidden "1"'s underneath my table to pick up the correct column.

Comment: An easier way to find the first "empty" column number in a row range is RowRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Cells(1).column

Answer (score 2):

```
Private Sub FormatSheet()
    iColumn = FindEmptyColumn()
    Cells(3, iColumn).Value = "Outer Surface"
    Cells(3, iColumn + 1).Value = "Inner Surface"
    Cells(3, iColumn + 2).Value = "Average"

    Columns(iColumn).ColumnWidth = 12
    Columns(iColumn + 1).ColumnWidth = 12.57
    Columns(iColumn + 2).ColumnWidth = 8.43

    Union(Columns(iColumn), Columns(iColumn + 1), Columns(iColumn + 2)).NumberFormat = "0.0000"
End Sub

Function FindEmptyColumn() As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        FindEmptyColumn = .Cells.Find("*", .Cells(1), xlFormulas, xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column + 1
        If Err <> 0 Then
            FindEmptyColumn = 0
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Well done, Alex P! I was wondering if someone would pick-up the ball in this thread. :)